# nested dictionary assert, return an error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Tags: python

I am trying to do something simple, but I always get an error ("TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str")

```
d = {}
d['1'] = {}
d['1']['2'] = {}
d['1'] = ["4", "5"]
d['1']['2'] = ["1", "2"]
print(d)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: You set `d['1']` to `["4", "5"]`, which is a list, which is why when you try to set the value `['2']` of that list, python gives an error as you can only apply string keys with dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d['1'] = ["4", "5"]
```

That line of code reassigns `d['1']` to be a list, so it's not a dictionary anymore.

Then you get the error on the next line

```
d['1']['2'] = ["1", "2"]
```

... because `d['1']` is now a list, and you're trying to get the `['2']` index, which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You're clobbering `d['1']`.

```
d = {}
d['1'] = {}
d['1']['2'] = {}
# d['1'] = {'2' : {}}, which is a dict
d['1'] = ["4", "5"]
# now d['1'] = ["4", "5"], which is a list
d['1']['2'] = ["1", "2"]
# that's the same as getting the ['2'] key out of the list ["4", "5"], which can't be done since lists need integer indices and you're giving it a string
```